# How to implement authentication for REST API?

Tags: python, api, authentication, rest, oauth

I'm creating a web based service that I want to expose as a REST API so that developers are able to create apps using it. I want developers to be able to create/manage user accounts and authenticate through API. How to handle this? OAuth or something else?

I'm using python,flask,mongodb for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have settled on the following, using [OAuth 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30) (which is much preferable to OAuth 1). In particular we are using the [resource owner password credentials](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-1.3.3) flow. As to how to integrate it into our RESTful service, here is the idea:

- The initial resource, when hit by an unauthorized user, returns a 401. The body of the 401 contains a single link, with [`rel=oauth2-token`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wmills-oauth-lrdd-00). (How you signal links depends on your media type; we're using [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), but you could use even just the `Link` header.)
- After the user authenticates, he returns to the initial resource, sending in his `Authorization` header the bearer token returned from the OAuth 2 process. At this point, we return a 200, with all the normal links available.

We don't expose account creation, but if you wanted to do that, I would do so with another link available to unauthorized users in the initial resource. That link would have a custom `rel` since it is specific to your application, e.g. `rel=http://rels.myapi.com/users`

Good RESTful design would indicate that the link with this `rel` points to e.g. `http://myapi.com/users`, and that consumers of the API do a `POST` to that endpoint, which returns to them the new user resource with a `Location` header pointing to the newly-created user resource at e.g. `http://myapi.com/users/username`. (User resources themselves would of course be another `rel`, distinguishing between the singular user resource and the plural users collection resource.)